# UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic with UITextView does not show up correctly

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uitextview, ios9, uitableviewautomaticdimension

On iOS 9, to  set up my tableView with UITableViewAutomaticDimension and a 200.f estimatedRowHeight on viewDidLoad.

```
[self.tableView setEstimatedRowHeight:200.f];
[self.tableView setRowHeight:UITableViewAutomaticDimension];
```

It works well for cells with images, buttons or labels but for a cell with a textView and button, the button appears correctly but the textView doesn't expand when once my tableView updated.

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1];
[self.tableView reloadSections:indexSet withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Do you have any ideas about want could be my mistake?

Should I update the heigth constraint programmatically in my cell?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, my UITextView was set as scrollable, I unchecked it in IB and now it works.